# The solution to a negative integrand in a double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Let's say you have the following double integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^0 \int_{a}^b -f(u-x) dudx, $$ where $F’(u-x) = f(u-x)$, $a \lt b$ and $F(\infty) = 0$.

Changing the order of integration, I would assume this solves to $\int_a^b-F(u) du$, but it seems this solves to $\int_a^b F(u) du$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: When you say $F(u-x)'$, do you mean the derivative of $F(u-x)$ with respect to $x$ or the derivative of $F$ evaluated at $u-x$? These have opposite sign, which may be a source of this sign error.

Comment: The derivative of $F$ evaluated at $(u-x)$ indeed...

Comment: Then you should write $F'(u-x)$.

Comment: Good point, edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F'=f$, then
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Bigl( F(u-x) \Bigr) = F'(u-x) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u-x) = f(u-x) \cdot (-1)
$$
by the chain rule. So the inner integral, after changing the order of integration, is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 (-f(u-x)) dx = \Bigl[ F(u-x) \Bigr]_{x=-\infty}^0 = F(u) - \lim_{t \to \infty} F(t) = F(u) - 0 = F(u)
.
$$